# How to periodically show alert message *in foreground* on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

I want to have an alert / dialog box to fire up periodically **in foreground** on my Mac.

I tried a combination of AppleScript and `launchd` and managed to have the script (actually converted to a app) fired up periodically via launchd. However, the alert box does not show up in front of all other windows (rather totally hidden until I tab to it – though it *does* get started via `launchd`). How can I get it in front?

My script is as follows:

```
on run
    activate me --> tried to get alert in foreground
                --> didn't help, though
    display alert "Should show up in foreground..."
end run
```

My launch.plist is (in `/Users/bernhard/Library/LaunchAgents/`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>bernhard.sitstraight.plist</string>

    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/bernhard/programming/periodic.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
    <true/>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1200</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/188632/128933):

The solution is to [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) the app, which seems to be more like a double-click on the app icon. That is, one has to replace the program to be called by `/usr/bin/open` and pass the app as an argument as follows within the launchd.plist:

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/usr/bin/open</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>open</string>
    <string>/Users/bernhard/programming/periodic.app</string>
</array>
```

The first argument (in this case `open`) actually gets passed as `argv[0]` and, hence, is not relevant here. The actual first argument then is `/Users/[...]/periodic.app` – the app directory rather than the actual binary.